# Overflowing a stack in theory.. and assembly

Tags: assembly, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow, shellcode

Assuming an x86 system with no aslr I'd like to ask the following;

1) Theory says that when we execute a stack overflow attack, the value pointed to by the ebp register is overwritten with the new return address too.

Now,  since we never go back to the caller function we don't really need ebp's original value to restore the previous stack frame  but nevertheless, ebp register must point somewhere at all times. How ebp is set after the eip register starts  pointing to our new shellcode? 
More specifically, which of the two assembly instructions (leave-ret) induces a further microinstruction which restores ebp to a value?

2) Last but not least, I would also like to ask how do we make sure that in occasions where our shellcode needs to push a couple of values on the stack, these values won't overwrite any part of the shellcode? In other words, how can we be certain that any shellcode generated variables will only be placed before the start of the shellcode and for instance not somewhere in between?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure that discussing the mechanics of a stack overflow attack on an open forum is a good idea - am I missing something?

Comment: `leave` is the one that does the thing with `ebp`.

Comment: @Floris Why not? Security by hiding your head in the sand never helped anyone in the long term.

Comment: @Floris I think it's acceptable at this level and refinement. Discussing (i.e. use of) tools to "crack passwords"; not so much.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs - I was trying to get a sense for what "the community" thinks, and I got my answer.

Comment: @pst The usage of password cracking tools is beyond the scope of [SO defined in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), as it is not related to programming. To learn more about the usage of eg. John the Ripper, [you can search security.stackexchange.com for "john"](http://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=john).

Comment: @nrz Please re-read my comment and context.

Comment: @pst I meant that I see no reason to discuss password cracking tools or other security tools that can be used also for malicious purposes (rootkits, port scanners, keyloggers etc.) in SO, when those topics belong more to the scope of http://security.stackexchange.com/ and there questions on those topics receive informed answers too.

Comment: @nrz **Please re-read my comment and context**. First, note it was address to Floris's initial comment "I'm not sure that discussing the mechanics of a stack overflow attack on an open forum is a good idea - am I missing something?". My reply was "I think it's acceptable at this level and refinement. Discussing (i.e. use of) tools to 'crack passwords'; not so much." Thus, it is clearly seen that I agree with this question here, in particular because it is *a practical question with an implementation*, but "not so much" for questions relating to the use of various security tools.

Comment: Can't help but add that it's ironic posts discussing the mechanics of "stack overflow" aren't allowed on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to part 2 of your question: Depending on the syscall you are making, you may have to put a value into `esp` (as an arg array). If that's the end of the shellcode then you are fine. However, if there is more to the shell code and you happen to do a `push` *and* the `esp` happens to point somewhere in the rest of your shellcode you might be in trouble (because at that point you will be writing over your own instructions). A simple fix is to do something like `sub $0x99, %esp` at the very beginning of the shellcode.

EDIT (in response to the comments)

Perhaps I misunderstood you question. When you said 'stack overflow' I assumed that you meant a buffer overflow. If I assumed correctly then read on. Assuming you really are talking about a classic smashing-the-stack sort of exploit (which seems to be the case based on the picture you linked to), then you are filling a buffer with a `nop` sled, `shellcode` and finally overwriting the return pointer. The shell code is "position independent code". That means that it is a series of instructions that can be executed regardless of the current state of the registers, flags etc.

Normally, (this is also the way the link that you posted depicts it) you fill the buffer with nops, followed by the shellcode, and finally a return address that points somewhere in tho nop sled. When the `ret` instruction is executed, the address in `%esp` is poped into `%eip` and `%esp` is incremented by 4 (in x86). The problem is that if your shellcode has several `push` instructions, this has a side effect of *decrementing* `%esp`. If you have enough of them *and* your shellcode is all the way at the end (i.e. adjacent to the return address) then you may end up overwriting your shellcode with the `push` instructions.

So, to actually answer your question. No, there is no 'mechanism' to separate your shellcode from 'its stack'. This is because there is no stack per-se for your shellcode. Remember, it is position independent code. It must be able to run regardless of machine state. Any stack management that needs to happen must be performed by the shellcode itself. That is why I suggested a `sub $0x99, %esp` at the begning of the shellcode if you have many `push` statements in the code. Another option is to make sure there sufficient space between the return address (which `%esp-4` will be pointing at) and your shellcode.

Comment: Please spare a few minutes of your time and have a look at a graph I snatched off the web and adapted accordingly for demonstration purposes. http://i46.tinypic.com/amis9.jpg

Comment: In this picture above you can clearly see a stack. The stack grows downwards. However when we read our data we do it the other way around. -So, according to your answer if "send" the esp pointer far down the stack, a few shellcode variables that the shellcode might need to push won't be a problem since we 'll be having 153 bytes in our disposal. However, what's stopping the system from placing the shellcode-generated-stack (assuming it ned=eds to push local variables on its own) on the address space that the shellcode is already stored itself?

Comment: In other words, is there any mechanism preventing the overlaying of the address space between the shellcode and its own stack? P.S I believe this was not a problem since the code is normally stored on the text segment and any needed stack space is reserved through the 'ENTER' function.

Comment: Thank you. That exactly was my point. Just a couple more clarifications and I think I'll be done here: Your suggestion of using `sub $0x99, %esp` now makes total sense but should only hold true if `esp - start_of_the_shellcode < 0x99`, is that correct? In other words you are suggesting that we'll have to "jump over" the address space of the shellcode in order to reach a safe address space for variable pushing, right? If that's the case,

Comment: then how do you explain that I read in an article that "the nop blocks are essentially protecting the trailing bytes of the shellcode of being overwritten in cases where the shellcode might have to push a few values of its own". Sorry if I wasn't clear enough from the get-go.

Answer (score 3):

1.When a function gets invoked, the value of `esp` gets copied onto `ebp`, then the stack frame for that particular function gets allocated by decreasing the value of `esp` (via `ENTER` instruction or `push ebp`; `mov ebp,esp`; `sub esp, SIZE`; instruction sequence). From this point on, the value of `esp` strictly grows upwards and thus does not interfere with the stack frame of the current function.

When the function reaches its end, it frees the stack frame by going through the steps described above, but backwards, i.e. via `LEAVE` instruction, or `mov esp, ebp`; `pop ebp`; instruction sequence. At this point, the value of `esp` points to the return address, and this is the address that the attacker wants to modify. Once this value is modified, upon the execution of `RET` instruction, the modified return address gets popped, and the `eip` now points to the modified address.

2.Since anything above your shellcode has been "freed", you simply need to allocate the stack frame for your shell code by going through the same steps described above.

Comment: You wrote that LEAVE equals add esp SIZE and pop ebp. How is ebp register supposed to restore its previous value since there is no i. e mov ebp DWORD PTR (esp) at this point? 

As for (2) the shellcode stack frame you are referring to may actually overlap in address space with the one used by the shellcode.

Comment: @Konos5 the value of `ebp` was pushed onto stack during `ENTER`. As for 2) No it won't. the shellcode has to lie *after* the modified return address. Otherwise the program will probably crash even before the function reaches the end.

Comment: Yes but pop alone doesn't restore the pushed value back to the ebp register... You will most probably need an instruction like the one I mentioned in my previous comment. In (2) shellcode does indeed reside after the modified return address but so do any local variables originating from the shellcode.  Return address -> saved frame pointer -> local variables.  What's stopping shellcode stack frame from sticking in between the last two?

Comment: @Konos5 that's what `LEAVE` is for. Not only does it pop ebp, but it also adjusts the stack frame by moving the value of ebp to esp. And what do you mean by local variables "originating from the shellcode"? Do you mean it might overwrite the stack frame of the caller? If so, of course it will. There's no way to avoid it. You don't expect the stack frame of the caller to be intact when you're injecting your shellcode. If you have the need to return to the caller after executing your shellcode, then it's the shellcode's job to reconstruct the caller's stack frame.

Comment: @Konos5  And there's no one-size-fits-all type of solution for that. It's going to depend on the stack frame of the caller.

Comment: Sorry it took me this long to get back to you. Please, let's take a step back now and examine what happens under NORMAL conditions. In LEAVE you said `mov esp, ebp` is used to adjust the size of the stack and makes esp point at the exact same location ebp is currently poining at. Then `pop ebp` steps in and essentially removes the saved frame pointer of the previous stack frame (let's assume it is main()). Now esp is supposed to point to the return address which will be copied over to the EIP register to continue executing from the designated address. The problem is that

Comment: by the time we popped the ebp value (or saved frame pointer value) from the stack, I can see no way of restoring the ebp register with its previous value (the one main() uses). How is this value supposed to be restored? I am a little confused over here and I would really appreciate it if you could shed some more light.

Comment: @Konos5 You have a valid point that it's difficult to predict the value of `ebp` *beforehand*. However, this can be easily calculated in your shellcode since its value is merely going to be some value greater than the value of `esp`. To be exact, it's going to be the `SIZE` (as in `sub esp, SIZE`), plus some displacement that resulted from pushing the parameters of the callee onto the stack.